# Probability of distributing $N$ different balls to numbered cells so the first $X$ cells will have more balls than the remaining cells

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $12$ **different** balls and $10$ numbered cells, the balls are distributed randomly. I need to calculate the probability that the number of balls in cells $1-5$ is greater than cells $6-10$ and give both algebraical and combinatorial explanation. so let $A$ be the event that the number of balls in cells $1-5$ is greater, $B$ the event that cells $6-10$ have more balls, and $C$ the event the number of balls is even. $$P(A)=P(B), P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1 \Longrightarrow 2P(A)=1-P(C) \Longrightarrow P(A)=0.5 - 0.5 * P(C)$$ where $P(C)=\binom{12}{6}\cdot{0.5}^{12}$ so I get $$P(A) = 0.5 - 0.5 * P(C) = 0.5 - \binom{12}{6}\cdot{0.5}^{13}$$ this covers the algebraical explanation but I'm finding it hard to formulate a combinatorial explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Combinatoric expression

Chance =

$$ \frac{\text{N(umerator)}}{\text{D(enominator)}}.$$

$$D = \sum_{k=0}^{12} \binom{12}{k} ~=~ 2^{(12)}.$$

$$N = \sum_{k=7}^{12} \binom{12}{k}.$$